# Collect data from cells and assign to a range. How to avoid automatic text to number?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to collect data from a large worksheet and paste to a target range.

The data mix with number and number like string (ex:"0050").

I tried a variant array to store the data and assign to a series of cells.

Here is the sample code:

```
Dim z() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
ReDim z(1 To 3, 1 To 1)
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    .Cells(1, 1) = "'" & "0050" 'content from cell A, could be number or number like string.
    .Cells(3, 1) = 20           'content from cell B, could be number or number like string.
    .Cells(5, 1) = "'" & "040"  'content from cell C, could be number or number like string.

    For i = 1 To 3
        z(i, 1) = .Cells(1 + (i - 1) * 2, 1)
    Next

    .Cells(1, 2).Resize(3, 1) = z

End With
```

Excel automatically changes the string "0050" to a number format so the value in cell(1,2) is 50, not "0050".

I want the cell's format to be the same as it originally was but I don't know each cell's format in advance.

I can use a loop to assign each cell to another but the running speed will be slow:

```
Dim z() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
ReDim z(1 To 3, 1 To 1)
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    .Cells(1, 1) = "'" & "0050" 'content from cell A, could be number or number like string.
    .Cells(3, 1) = 20           'content from cell B, could be number or number like string.
    .Cells(5, 1) = "'" & "040"  'content from cell C, could be number or number like string.

    For i = 1 To 3
        .Cells(i, 2) = .Cells(1 + (i - 1) * 2, 1)
    Next

End With
```

Is there a way to avoid Excel automatically changing the string to number?

Comment: Instead of setting the cell values directly, maybe you can use a variable to hold the value of the expression first. Then you can set the value of the cell to the value of the variable as text. All of this within the loop that you have already written

Comment: @kerwei
The variant array can store both string and number, and it does store "0050" as string type variable. However when I assign it to a range, it become number format. I am not sure if I misunderstand your point.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim str As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        str = "00005"

        With .Range("A1")
            'Change cell format to TEXT before you enter value
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = str
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: .cells(1,1) = .cells(1,2) can result the same like I said. I am trying to assign an array to a range with faster running speed instead of cell to cell one by one. Any idea how to do that?